# How To Add Server Side Rendering To React Single Page App?

Tags: reactjs, server, ebay-api

I built a React app a year ago, and totally stopped working with React, so I am really really rusty.

Site is here: http://allvintagesearch.com

I'm using eBay API.

I'm sort of afraid to touch it, so wondering if there are any tips someone can provide in adding the ability for this site to get better rankings in google (right now there is really not much traffic).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m confused about your question title vs. the content of your question. What are you asking?

Comment: Sorry I'm not even sure if title is the right question and right way to phrase it.  Basically i'm not ranking in google, because of fact its a SPA in react.  I'm not sure how to fix that.  I am using express server on backend to connect to API and then display the information selected by user.  But I'm not exactly sure what to do now to get Title tags etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your site is static you can use Gatsby, otherwise, your best option is NextJs. you can check their doc. you can also find very good tutorials online.

[NextJs](https://nextjs.org/)

[Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/)

Comment: so dynamic content pulled from eBay based on user selection of my preset query tabs on my site. So you are saying i would need to re-build from scratch?

Comment: no, almost all of your react components are valid, just you have to configure it a little bit so that you can get the best of next js

Answer (score 1):

There are some websites like https://website.grader.com/ that they give you scores about every aspects of your website (e.g performance, security , SEO and etc) and then they tell you what you are missing and how to fix them. for google search i would recommend you to have look to this link:

[Get your website on Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34397?hl=en)

hope it gives you some help to start from.

Comment: thanks appreciated, it seems as if my site is getting ranked in google no problem, it's just the data that my api is pulling is not appearing in the search results